# Is there a way to test other assertions inside a test after calling tSQLt.ExpectException?

Tags: tsqlt

Using tSQLt 1.0.5873.27393, I'm trying to write a tSQLt test for a stored procedure that records errors trapped in a `CATCH` block to a log table before re-throwing the error to the calling session.

I can successfully test that the error message is re-thrown using `tSQLt.ExpectException`, but a side effect seems to be that it's not possible to test any other assertions after calling `tSQLt.ExpectException` - so I am unable to test whether the error has been written to the log table.

The simplest test that I can come up with which demonstrates the problem is:

```
CREATE PROC MyTests.[test ExpectException]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException;
    THROW 50001, 'Error message',1

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 0,1, '0=1'
END
GO
```

which produces the following (unexpected) output when executed:

```
|No|Test Case Name                  |Dur(ms)|Result |
+--+--------------------------------+-------+-------+
|1 |[MyTests].[test ExpectException]|      3|Success|
```

Using a profiler trace, I can see that the `AssertEquals` assertion is never executed, because the error is trapped by a `CATCH` block inside `tSQLt.Private_RunTest`.

Because tSQLt uses `CATCH` to trap errors, I suspect that there's no solution to this problem without a major rewrite of tSQLt - but I ask here just in case others have found a way around the issue.

Comment: Suggestion/best practice: make your tests as atomic as possible (testing one thing at a time). I would split this scenario in two tests (one for the error and one for the logging).

Comment: @EduardUta - I would do this if I could but in this case it isn't possible; the code path I'm testing is only exercised when an error is thrown, and the error is always subsequently re-thrown.

Comment: Yes, you can. One test that uses ExpectException and another that looks only at the log table using the TRY...CATCH approach.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow this approach:

In the test, wrap your call to the tested stored procedure in a try/catch block.
Before the try/catch block, set up an expected variable to 1 and actual to 0.
In the test catch block, check if the log table got populated and if yes then flip the actual variable to 1.
Write your assertion AFTER the catch block.

```
CREATE PROC MyTests.[test ExpectException]
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @expected bit = 1;
    DECLARE @actual bit = 0;

    BEGIN TRY
        -- call tested SP, make sure it fails
        CALL SP..;

        -- add safety net, if the SP call doesn't fail then fail the test
        RAISERROR('Fail the test', 16, 1);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- pseudo code
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM log table)
        -> flip @actual to 1
    END CATCH

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals @expected, @actual
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eduard Uta got there before I did, but I'll post this anyway.

---

It dawned on me almost as soon as I'd posted this that the obvious solution is to use a custom `TRY...CATCH` block, rather than the built-in tSQLt objects:

```
CREATE PROC MyTests.[test custom try catch]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorRaised bit = 0

    BEGIN TRY
        THROW 50001, 'Error message',1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ErrorRaised = 1
    END CATCH

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 1,@ErrorRaised, 'Error raised'

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 0,1, '0=1'
END
GO
```

Here's an example which tests for a specific error message:

```
CREATE PROC MyTests.[test custom try catch test message]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ErrorRaised bit = 0

    BEGIN TRY
        THROW 50001, 'Error message',1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF ERROR_MESSAGE() = 'Error message'
            SET @ErrorRaised = 1
        ELSE
            THROW
    END CATCH

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 1,@ErrorRaised, 'Error raised'

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 0,1, '0=1'
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, calling both the procedure under test and the tSQLt ExpectException proc inside a TRY...CATCH block seems to have done the trick.

```
CREATE PROC MyTests.[test ExpectException]
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    -- Call the proc that raises the error
    EXEC offending_stored_proc

    -- Tell tSQLt to expect the exception
    EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedMessage = 'Expected error message', @ExpectedSeverity = NULL, @ExpectedState = NULL;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    -- No need to do anything here
  END CATCH
END;
```

As expected, if the procedure raises the error with that error message, the test passes. If the error is not raised, the test fails.